# Convert data type series to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column that is a Series and I want to convert to a datetime format. This particular column of my data frame looks like below:

```
x
Aug 1, 2019 7:20:04 AM
Aug 1, 2019 7:20:14 AM
Aug 1, 2019 7:20:24 AM
Aug 1, 2019 7:20:34 AM
```

I've seem some answers here and I tried to adapt my code accordingly.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(df["x"],'%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %a').strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

But I get the following error:

> strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

For this reason, I tried to convert to string using the following:

```
df['x'] = df['x'].apply(str)
df['x'] = df['x'].to_string()
df['x'] = df['x'].astype(str)
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are using `pandas`. You can use pandas `to_datetime()` function instead of datetimes functions which can only convert a single value for a given call. Also for AM/PM you need `%p` instead of `%a`

```
df['x'] = pd.to_datetime(df['x'], format="%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p")
```

---

***Edit***

Check to make sure your data is exactly how you posted it. I copy and pasted your data, and created a data frame and it works without an error.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['Aug 1, 2019 7:20:04 AM','Aug 1, 2019 7:20:14 AM','Aug 1, 2019 7:20:24 AM','Aug 1, 2019 7:20:34 AM']})
```

Output:

```
                        x
0  Aug 1, 2019 7:20:04 AM
1  Aug 1, 2019 7:20:14 AM
2  Aug 1, 2019 7:20:24 AM
3  Aug 1, 2019 7:20:34 AM



df['x'] = pd.to_datetime(df['x'],format='%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p')
```

Output:

```
                    x
0 2019-08-01 07:20:04
1 2019-08-01 07:20:14
2 2019-08-01 07:20:24
3 2019-08-01 07:20:34
```

Comment: You could also make a lambda function and use DataFrame.apply to get it done element-wisely, but I think your solution is more clear.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I still get a error: "does not match format '%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %a'"

Comment: Still does not work. Same type of error: does not match format '%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p'

Comment: Not sure why since it works for me. Try printing your data out and make sure it matches and you have the correct column.

Comment: I restarted the Kernel and now it works. Thanks a lot!